# ksoap(web services) example in android using SoapPrimitive

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

1. this code is not giving  me any errors or warning but is not working properly ,I did not know where is the                                                problem,Please help me.

   ```
   package com.example.webtest;

   import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
   import android.util.Log;
   import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
   import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
   import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
   import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   String UserFahrenheit;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
   final EditText Med=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.MedServTextView);
   final TextView Test=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TestTextView);

   b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           //try{
               UserFahrenheit=Med.getText().toString();

               //String mobile=getData(UserMRN.trim());
                String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
                   String METHOD_NAME = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
                   String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/FahrenheitToCelsius";
                   String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";

                   SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                   Request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",UserFahrenheit.trim());

                   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                           SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                   envelope.dotNet = true;
                   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

                   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                           URL);
       try{
                   androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                   SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                   String Celsius;
                   Celsius= String.valueOf(response.toString());
                  Test.setText(Celsius);

       }catch(Exception e){
           e.getMessage();
       }



       //  }catch(Exception e){
       //      e.getMessage();
       //  }


       }
   });

       }



   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: have you get response from web services.?

Comment: Just small comment - doing long operations on the ui thread is way to be killed by Android and bad UX experience

Comment: Log your error in catch block you must be getting an exception

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a SoapPrimitive? First of all, check if your response is an Error. Otherwise, get de responsebody from the response object by calling response.bodyIn:

```
SoapObject response = null;
if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapObject) { // SoapObject = SUCCESS
    response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
} else if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) { // SoapFault =
                                                    // FAILURE
    SoapFault soapFault = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
    throw new Exception(soapFault.getMessage());
}
```

Then, you can get properties from your response by calling response.getProperty("responsecode") for example.

Also, put the debug value of your HttpTransportSE on true while debugging:

```
transportSE.debug = true;
```

Comment: _**I am using SoapPrimitive becouse I return primitive value(String) from web services ,I also using SoabObject but it giving me NullPointerException in this statment  SoapObject pii = (SoapObject)soap.getProperty(0).toString(); I did not know how to solve this problem so I swap this with SoapPrimitive_**

Comment: Don't directly parse your response to a string. You need to get the body of your response with the method bodyIn of your envelope, instead of calling getResponse() from the envelope. What is the value bodyIn returns?

Comment: I am using bodyIn  but is not giving me any result